# How to add UIImages to an NSMutableArray, and change the images later?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I am making a simple game that requires that I draw multiple UIImages in many different places. My problem here is that I need to add the UIImages to an NSMutableArray, and access them later. Using NSStrings to represent the images (such as for paths) will not work here, so I need to know how to change the images for every UIImage in the array.

My code is as follows (at least, for accessing the NSMutableArray). The NSMutableArray is declared in my .h file, and is initialized in a different method.

```
for (int a = 0; a <= [theArray count]; a ++) {
    // I make a UIImage, which I will draw later
    UIImage *theImage = [theArray objectAtIndex:a];
    // then I do the drawing
}
```

This works fine. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to change a particular object in the NSMutableArray. How can I do this?

By the way, I am adding the UIImages to the NSMutableArray with the following code.

```
+ (void) createCarWithImage:(NSString*)theImageName {
    UIImage *anImage= [UIImage imageNamed:theImageName];
    [theArray addObject:anImage];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use this method:

```
- (void)replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(id)anObject
```

e.g.:

```
[theArray replaceObjectAtIndex:4 withObject:someOtherImage];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just modify each `UIImage` in the `NSMutableArray` as is, you only have a pointer to the actual data. That is, regardless of what pointer you use to change the data, the data is changed for every pointer.

Additionally, you can also iterate over your `UIImage`s with:

```
for (UIImage *img in theArray)
{
     //send messages to img
}
```

---

Answer to Comment

You can modify the `UIImage` at index 4 by:

```
UIImage *image = [theArray objectAtIndex:4];
//send messages to image
```

Comment: How do I modify the image? That was my question, but this answer does not tell me how.

Comment: Modify it by sending each image messages that [`UIImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) responds to. Are you looking for scaling, translating, etc or are you looking for modifying pixel by pixel?

Comment: I do not think we are understanding each other here. How can I change the image without using the `for` loop? For instance, if I wanted to modify the image at index @"4", what do I have to do?

Comment: I updated my answer to answer your current question. As far as modification goes, its just like manipulating any other object. You send it messages it responds to.