# How to load remote Images and save to a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, afnetworking

I am trying to Load 5 or 6 remotes images to a scrollview and swipe horizontal. I can get the URLs form my webserver (JSON output) , I'm trying to do this using AFnetworking for performances issues .

so far I can get the URL and load one picture to a UIImageview  like this (Using Storyboard )

```
Jsonobject *items = [posterNSMarray objectAtIndex:0]; //load one url only 
NSlog (@"Object url %@", items.pUrl); //  picture URL
[self.imageview setImageWithURl :[NSURL URLWithString:items.pUrl] placeholderImage :[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
```

**[EDITED QUESTION]**
my question is how do I get all the images and save it to a NSMutableArray

Thanks for your help .

Comment: please use lazy loading concept

Comment: i didnt get the question, what is the behavior you are trying to achieve?

Comment: load 5 images to scrollview and scroll/swipe through images one at the time . thanks

Comment: @elppa I though that by using AFNetworking I was using the same concept as Lazy Loading ?

Comment: see my answer, i think your problem is solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[EDIT]**
Based upon your comments below, I might actually choose then a different methodology
Bring in All of your images.  At this point you can use either UIImageView or UIButton actually to obtain the tap (from the scrollview) you wish.  Assign the UIImages to your choice of UIButton or UIImageView, and the place them on your scrollview as you wish.  You will have to dynamically create the actions for each Button or ImageView.  Your action creation should then bring up another View to be place atop you scrollview, or another viewcontroller that you animate to, etc...  In a View Controller you will have your UIImageView as full screen.  At this point you can implement your own UIGestureRecognizers to implement the double taps, etc...

I would use a UIListView.  Here is a great link to custom UIListView implementation.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

I would load your images into an NSMutableArray, to be used by the drawing routine of the custom UITableView.

As for swiping, you can capture the swipe events, then you can do with the list items as you please (i.e. delete, edit, etc... from your image array).

Another link:
http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/

Comment: Hi Thanks but I don't want to use table view, I want to use the scrollview and paging .

Comment: Scrollviews still have to have a some sort of view within them.  You could always just have a generic UIView as your canvas and place UIImages on top of the UIView

Comment: So you would have your UIView as subview to your ScrollView, then you would assign UIImages to UIImageViews, the use the addSubview routine.  From there you can place them where you want on the UIView "canvas" with the frame property.

Comment: yea I can do that but I want something more interactive , the same as the table view is just boring. thanks

Comment: What type of interactivity are you really after? I would love to help!

Comment: just a scroll the user can scroll left or right , then tap the image to full size , double tap to zoom out .. thanks for your help ..

Answer (score 0):

From your question and comments it seems like you want to load a UIScrollView with multiple images and then swipe through each one.  It also sounds like you want to be able to tap one and have it launch a blown up image for the user to view.

I wrote some of these functions for an old project (they are a little rough) but you may be able to use them as they are how I accomplished what I think you were asking.

```
-(void)setupPictures
{
    imageSectionSlider = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];
    imageSectionSlider.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    imageSectionSlider.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    imageSectionSlider.pagingEnabled = YES;
    imageSectionSlider.bounces = NO;


    UIView* tilesHolder = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (([[thisStory imageList]count] * (self.frame.size.width))), IMAGE_HEIGHT)];
tilesHolder.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    for (int count = 0; count < [[thisStory imageList]count]; count++) 
    {
        [tilesHolder addSubview:[self createImageTile:[[thisStory imageList]objectAtIndex:count] Count:count Rect:CGRectMake(  320*count , 0, 320, IMAGE_HEIGHT)]];
    }

    [imageSectionSlider setContentSize:CGSizeMake( tilesHolder.frame.size.width , tilesHolder.frame.size.height)];
    [imageSectionSlider addSubview:tilesHolder];
    [tilesHolder release];
}


-(UIView*)createImageTile:(ImageItem*)input Count:(int)count Rect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIView* imageTile = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
    [imageTile setTag:count];

    UIImageView* image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageTile.frame.size.width, imageTile.frame.size.height - 45)];
    [image setImage:[input imageData]];
    image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; 
    image.clipsToBounds = YES;
    image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    image.tag = count;

    UIGestureRecognizer* featureImageGesRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(countTaps:)];
    [image addGestureRecognizer:featureImageGesRec];
    [featureImageGesRec release];

    [imageTile addSubview:image];
    [image release];
    return [imageTile autorelease];
}

- (void)countTaps:(NSObject*)sender {
    tapCount++;
    if (tapCount == 1) {
    //do something with single tap
    }
    else if (tapCount == 2)
    {   
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
        [self doubleTap:sender];
    }
}

-(void)doubleTap:(NSObject*)sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer* item = (UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender;
    tapCount = 0;
//FullSizeImage
    ImageItem* selectedItem = [[thisStory imageList]objectAtIndex:item.view.tag];
    ExpandedView* pictureView = [[ExpandedView alloc]initWithImage:[selectedItem imageData]];
    [thisParent.navigationController pushViewController:pictureView animated:YES];
    [pictureView release];

}
```

Just pass your async loaded image here in this line...

```
 [tilesHolder addSubview:[self createImageTile:/*Image*/ Count:count Rect:CGRectMake(  320*count , 0, 320, IMAGE_HEIGHT)]];
```

Comment: what I am having problems with is to save the images to an NSMutableArray ? thanks.

Comment: + (void) createCarWithImage:(NSString*)theImageName {
    UIImage *anImage= [UIImage imageNamed:theImageName];
    [theArray addObject:anImage];
} I got this from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005870/how-to-add-uiimages-to-an-nsmutablearray-and-change-the-images-later

Answer (score 0):

if you use AFNetworking Conect, you use Image Request concept :- 
 try this code:-

```
 - (void)setupPage
{
    scrollPage = 0 ;

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0, 320,367)];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [scrollView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    NSUInteger nimages = 0;
    CGFloat cx = 0;
    CGFloat cy = 0;

    for (; nimages < [stealArr count]; nimages++)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,320.0f,367)];

        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;

        rect.size.height = 331;
        rect.size.width = 320.0f;

        rect.origin.y = 0.0f;
        rect.origin.x = 0.0f+cx;

        imageView.frame = rect;

        [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];

    [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/r4uwx.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderImage"]];

        cx += scrollView.frame.size.width;
        cy += scrollView.frame.size.height;

    }   


    pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 331.0f, 320, 36)] ;
    [pageControl setCurrentPage:0] ;
    [pageControl addTarget: self action: @selector(pageControlClicked:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged] ;
    [pageControl setDefersCurrentPageDisplay: YES];
    [pageControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:pageControl];

    pageControl.numberOfPages = [stealArr count];

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx,[scrollView bounds].size.height)];

    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:TRUE];
}
 when Your are scroll the page

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    // We don't want a "feedback loop" between the UIPageControl and the scroll delegate in
    // which a scroll event generated from the user hitting the page control triggers updates from
    // the delegate method. We use a boolean to disable the delegate logic when the page control is used.
    // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    scrollPage = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    pageControl.currentPage = scrollPage;

    be to unload the views+controllers which are no longer visible
}

     for Paging
    - (void)pageControlClicked:(id)sender
    {
        UIPageControl *thePageControl = (UIPageControl *)sender ;

        // we need to scroll to the new index
        [scrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width * thePageControl.currentPage, scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated: YES] ;
    }
```